# Because property photos.name comes back to me as if I'm doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm having an error with vue.js and laravel but I can't figure out how can I get this array/object inside coded
in a nutshell I connected to the room the instance photos via the has many of laravel and the output in the api call is like this **:**

[image: Photos]

I would like to just get the `name` from inside photos and then bring it into the frontend but every time I do that it tells me undefined as if I'm doing wrong method of entry.

Code frontend **:**

```
 <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(room, index) in rooms" :key="index">
                <div class="card mb-3 border-0">
                    **<img :src="'/img/rooms/'+room.photos.name" class="card-img-top br0" :alt="room.photos.name">**
                    
                    <p class="small text-uppercase pb-0">{{ room.listing_name }}</p>
                    <div class="card-body p-0">

                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ room.listing_name }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text m-0">${{ room.price }}/night</p>
                        <p class="small m-0 text-info">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;
                        <span class="text-secondary"> {{ index }}, Superhost</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: front-end]

Comment: photos is an **Array** ... so it'd be `rooms[0].name` for example - if you want to get all the photos , you'd need another nested `v-for`

Answer (score 0):

`photos` is an array:

```
<img :src="'/img/rooms/'+room.photos[0].name" class="card-img-top br0" :alt="room.photos[0].name">
```

Or you can iterate:

```
<img v-for="photo in room.photos" :src="'/img/rooms/'+photo.name" class="card-img-top br0" :alt="photo.name">
```

Answer (score 0):

`photos` is an Array of objects. Hence, Elements should be access via index.

You have to add one more iteration for photos via `v-for`.

```
<img v-for="photo in room.photos"
 :key="photo.id"
 :src="`/img/rooms/${photo.name}`"
 class="card-img-top br0"
 :alt="photo.name"
/>
```

Answer (score -4):

The image tag should be something like this:

```
<img src="/img/rooms/{{room.photos.name}}" alt="">
```

Comment: This way it will give you error